# Why can't get the selected item in the filtered list of AutoCompleteTextField?

Tags: codenameone

I define a DefaultListModel in an AutoCompleteTextField.

```
    DefaultListModel<String> options = new DefaultListModel<>();
    AutoCompleteTextField labelACField = new AutoCompleteTextField(options){
        @Override
        protected boolean filter(String text) {.......

    labelACField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            if (filteredIdObjs!=null){
                selectedIdx = options.getSelectedIndex();
                selectedIdObj = filteredIdObjs[selectedIdx];
                oidx = selectedIdObj.getId();
            }
        }              
    });
```

A User key in 'ss' in labelACField that show a list with 4 items.
The user selects the 3rd item - DS Drive shake Inc. but options.getSelectedIndex() always return 0. How do I get the user-selected item(the 3rd item)?
[image]

Comment: When you select an item it becomes the text. You need to use `getText()` it's a text field.

Comment: I select DS Drive Shack Inc but AutoCompleteTextField returns the first item S Sentine as its text. options.getSelectedIndex() always return 0, not the item index I selected. I hope getText() can return the selected item text but not return the first item.

Comment: There's no guarantee the list model selection will change. Only a guarantee about the `getText()` method. If that doesn't work I'll need a proper test case I can run.